# Why is my answer being displayed with "Subscript^(0,1)[a,b]"?

Tags: output-formatting, syntax

I type in my equations using ctrl+- to make it look nice and my answer outputs in "Subscript^(0,1)[a,b]" form? What is going on? In the answer some bits are displayed with the actual subscripts and some are displayed in the above form, even for the same variable.

Edit: more specifics I am taking the partial derivative of a function H wrt to b. H is a function of many variables one of which is a_b. Is it possible that Mathematica is trying to take the derivative of the subscript because there is a b in there?

```
H=d k2 + c^2 k4 + k5 s^2 + k1 U + 
 k3 \[Theta] + (g (1 - d - U - \[Theta]) \[Theta] - 
    U (1 + s Subscript[e, s])) Subscript[\[Lambda], 
  1] + (-c d + s U Subscript[e, s]) Subscript[\[Lambda], 2] + 
 U Subscript[\[Lambda], 3]
```

and

```
DHds = Simplify[D[H, s]]
```

Comment: How about a real example...

Comment: It looks like you might be taking partial derivatives of subscripted variables. The most useful answer is: Don't use Ctrl- to make it "look nice"... that's the problem right there! They only look nice, but are a pain in the butt when you want to do other things with them (also depends on what you want to do).

Comment: You can select the cell contained your code and press Ctrl+Shift+I to change it into `InputForm` before you paste your code here.

Comment: I remember someone saying that mathematica SE was the friendliest and best SE for nicely getting new users to improve their question writing so that they stayed and became part of the community instead of leaving with with their tail between their legs like they do on many SEs, at the time I didn't know about this SEs existence but now I know exactly what they were talking about. Thanks for putting up with my crummy questions @xzczd and rm-rf

Comment: As *rm-rf* said, generally a PITA to use in the way you seem to want, but if you insist on "prettiness", you can just enclose the subscripts in your original definitions in double-quotes...

Comment: Try this: use `es` instead of `Subscript[e, s]`, `λ1` instead of `Subscript[λ, 
   1]`, etc. and do the computations. Finally, to "prettify" the output, do `DHds /. {es -> Subscript[e, s], λ1 -> Subscript[λ, 
   1], λ2 -> Subscript[λ, 2]}`

Comment: In the edited text you say that you take the derivatve wrt b and that there is a a_b, but in the code I see the derivative rt s and e_s. So which is which? Please clarify and edit.

Comment: Also related: [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/89), [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19783/89) and many more.